# После обновления jQuery форма перестала обрабатываться

Tags: jquery, ajax, форма

В общем, есть форма, с неё аяксом тащится всё эт дело и отправляется на пых для обработки, далее - вешается ответ.

Вчера, обновив jQuery форма перестала обрабатываться. Т.е. - перекидывается прямиком по action, хотя до этого скрипт перехватывал method и action и всё обрабатывалось без перезагрузки страницы.

В тот же момент были подключены несколько плагинов, использующих свои типы бибилиотеки jQuey.

А теперь вопрос: может ли мой аякс по ошибке использовать библиотеку какого нибудь из плагинов? т.к. проверив всё по отдельности - работает. И как это можно попытаться вылечить?

UPD: В общем, залил старые версии всех скриптов - всё снова заработало. Но всё равно хочется знать, как это лечить, дабы не было проблем в будущем.
А пока пойду курить доку по jquery

Comment: Во-первых какую ошибку выдает отладчик?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined 

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тексту ошибки, она связана с тем, что свойство `browser` из jQuery [убрали](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) в версии 1.9. Вам может помочь плагин [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

Comment: сейчас попробоую и отпишусь

Comment: подключил плагин jQuery migrate - эмоций ноль, всё те же проблемы - не обрабатывается форма, закосячилось выпадающее меню и тд.

Comment: jQuery migrate теперь ругается ошибкой :

JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение, чтобы вы видели, что используете устаревшее API. Свойство `browser` при этом работает корректно. Воспользуйтесь отладчиком, чтобы выяснить, где именно вылетает сообщение

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @fori1ton уже всё нашел, разобрался что к чему, сижу переписываю.